# Is it possible to efficiently compute a cellular automata with arbitrary insertions on the GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

### Cellular automaton

A cellular automaton can be seen as an array of bits, plus a computation table that dictates that bits must be continuously updated as a function of their neighbors. For example,

```
111 -> 0
110 -> 0
101 -> 0
100 -> 1
011 -> 1
010 -> 1
001 -> 1
000 -> 0
```

That table dictates that whenever the array contains a `110` sequence, the middle bit must flip. This is repeated over and over globally, causing the array to evolve in interesting ways. Such computation can be performed efficiently on GPUs, since one can easily pre-load slices into the shared memory of a Streaming Multiprocessor.

[image: rule 34]

### Cellular automaton with insertions and deletions

Now, suppose we have a different kind of automata, where the array size can dynamically change, and on which certain rules cause a new bit to be inserted. For example:

```
111 -> 0
110 -> 00
101 -> 
100 -> 1
011 -> 00
010 -> 
001 -> 1
000 -> 0
```

This is similar to the previous computation, except that, now, whenever there is a `110` sequence on the array, not only the middle bit must flip, but a new bit, `0`, must be inserted right next to it. Moreover, when we have the `101` sequence, the middle bit must be removed.

Obviously, implementing this new problem using the same data structure, an array, would be prohibitive, since inserting a bit on the middle of an array requires shifting all the posterior elements 1 index right, which would be extremely expensive.

### Question

Is there any clever data structure or general approach that allows this computation to be performed efficiently on the GPU?

Comment: Did you try SOA instead of AOS? Instead of having different length memory per cell, why don't you try multiple maps each for a different element of arrays of cells? I mean, multiple 2D slices coming together to form 3D map from left to right points to elements of each cell. So you can easily preload all elements again.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing that comes to mind is a linked list, just effects the neighboring elements while the others can keep there references

Comment: The problem with linked lists is that now bits are shuffled all a round the global memory instead of stored locally. That means you can't take slices of the array to reduce in shared memory.

Comment: shoot I suppose that is true, arrays of boolean pointers perhaps would do the trick, you could insert, delete, and slice from those fairly efficiently i would imagine